# Umbraco SaveEventHandler code only runs the first time

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, umbraco

This is a strange problem that I'm having, and I'm not sure whether it's an Umbraco issue or something more high level.

To explain: we have a node where a back-end user uploads a file, and then ticks a box and presses save. When they press save, if the tickbox is ticked, then we should process what they uploaded. To achieve this, I call a function using the `Document.AfterSafe += new Document.SaveEventHandler(MethodCall)` line, and then I check that the checkbox is ticked, and go from there.

This all works for the first time. But when a user uploads a new file a couple of days later, the code doesn't run. The only way to get it to run, is to re-copy the .dll into the "bin" folder, and then press save.

Does this ring a bell for anyone at all? It seems as though the .dll stops listening for the SaveEventHandler after the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused by a global variable being declared before the constructor. The issue was solved on the Umbraco developer site [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/41431-SaveEventHandler-code-only-runs-the-first-time#).